# Barcode issue in Windows Mobile App for Intermec cn50

Tags: .net, lazarus, windows-mobile-6.1, intermec

I'm working on a Windows Mobile 6.1 app for take inventory, change price and another things, but when i want to read a bar code doesn't print the code in the input. Is not a scanner problem because when i push the buttom outside the app will print the numbers. I already investigate and can be a settings from de intermec but i haven't the icon to access a Intermec Settings i tried some tricks from google and nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

the problem does not seems to be intermec settings since you can print it outside of your application.

are you using any textboxts to receive the scanned input? have it focus on the textboxt?